# Trusted Publisher Certificate installation

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, certificate

Is there any way we can **add certificate** using cmd/shell/bat **silently without administrator rights** in windows 10.

I have a command which silently add cert in "Trusted Publisher" :

```
certutil -addstore "TrustedPublisher" my_certificate.cer
```

But this command needs administrator command prompt to run.

Comment: This would defeat the purpose of certificates... If you're OK with a batch that ask automatically for elevation, it's easy to give you an answer, but otherwise, you're trying to break a required security.

Comment: I am ok with batch. I have no intention to bypass security it was just to implement a feature for better customer experience. I need to ultimately install drivers which are required for hardware connection. So, to install drivers silently I need to add certificate in trusted publisher. Earlier version of windows won't required such elevations tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments below question, this batch should answer your needs:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Check admin mode, auto-elevate if required.
openfiles > NUL 2>&1 || (
    REM Not elevated. Do it.
    echo createObject^("Shell.Application"^).shellExecute "%~dpnx0", "%*", "", "runas">"%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs"
    cscript /nologo "%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs"
    goto :eof
)
del /s /q "%TEMP%\%~n0.vbs" > NUL 2>&1

REM Can't be here without elevation.
certutil -addstore "TrustedPublisher" my_certificate.cer

goto :eof
```

The batch will ask for elevation automatically and then execute your command, in an elevated `cmd`, and terminate.

### How it works:

`openfiles` is a standard program shipped with Windows 10 (for Windows 7, for example, I used to do that with `fsutils` instead).

This program have a particularity: it requires elevation, does nothing harmful with no parameter, *and returns a suitable error code without elevation*.

So, when you launch it *without* elevation, it prints an error message and **returns 1**.
*With* elevation, it prints things and **returns 0**.
Because we don't care about what it displays, both its `stdout` and `stderr` are sent to `NUL`.

So, when we're **NOT** elevated, the `||` operator will execute the code within parentheses. Otherwise, it skips it and go to the `del` line just after - this line is designed to clean the temporary file used for elevation, I'll explain it below.

So, we're not elevated. The purpose is to create a very tiny VBS script, within `%TEMP%` folder. In order to not mess with multiple batchs launched simultaneously, we name this temporary file following the current batch filename (that's the "%TEMP%%~n0.vbs" part).

The VBS contains a single command: it will call "ShellExecute" on the batch file itself (NOT the VBS), with all seen parameters (they're expanded when creating the VBS file, they're not passed to VBS then to BAT again) using the `runas` keyword - and here is the magic.

This keyword does this (see [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch)):

> **runas**     Launches an application as Administrator. User Account Control (UAC) will prompt the user for consent to run the application elevated or enter the credentials of an administrator account used to run the application.

Unfortunately, we can't call this function directly from a batch (at least not without some ugly tricks), but it's very easy and understandable to do so from a VBS. And VBS is standard on Windows, too.

So, we now launch the VBS, and we terminate the non-elevated batch with `goto :eof`. The VBS starts, and relaunch the batch, but with elevation (and an UAC prompt). The batch starts again, has all its previous command line parameters, will detect that it's already elevated.
We just need now to clean the temporary VBS file with the `del` command, and we can continue our batch being sure that we are in an elevated process.

Comment: Thanks for the help, altho it pops up the cmd to run as admin but that will work.

Comment: Pleasure mine. You can try by using `start /b` or `start /min` to launch your process, but I never tried it with auto-elevation. I highly doubt that you can make the elevated process totally invisible, I think that at best it will be minimized, but there is high chances that a command prompt window flashes on screen anyway.

Comment: ok i will try that as well

Comment: Hi @Wisblade can you explain the script you mentioned to get elevation for cmd?

Comment: @Yash Sure. I added a block to my answer, please check.